# Segfault with memory reallocation structure and linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, structure, valgrind

I am new to C and I am working on a project which I have been struggling with trying to get working for days and I cannot figure out where the problem is.

Basically, what the application is supposed to do is read data from a database and insert the values into a structure. Some rows are related to each so within the structure is a linked list which will contain other values from the database.

I do not know how many records I am going to get out of the database, so I initially malloc the structure to be 100 items, and I keep track of an index which if it reaches 100, it then reallocs the structures to add another 100 items. The reallocation bit seems to work but it is then why I try to insert something into the linked list within the structure I get a segfault.

Below is the definition for the main structure.

```
typedef struct CallLogSearchDataStruct
{
    char * date;
    char * time;
    char * bParty;
    char * aParty;
    float duration;
    char * cleardownCause;
    struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundLegs;
} callLogSearchDataStruct;
```

Below is the code for the linked list (CallLogSearchOutboundStruct)

```
typedef struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct
{
    char * target;
    float duration;
    char * cleardownCause;
    struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct * nextLeg;
} callLogSearchOutboundStruct;
```

I initialise the structures using the following code

```
callLogSearchData = calloc(INITIAL_CALL_STRUCT_SIZE,sizeof(callLogSearchDataStruct));
callLogSearch = calloc(INITIAL_CALL_STRUCT_SIZE,sizeof(callLogSearchResultStruct));
switches = calloc(INITIAL_CALL_STRUCT_SIZE, sizeof(switchIDStructure));
```

Each time it loops around the data, I malloc the outboundLeg linked list within the structure using the following code

```
if (dataRow > -1 && callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs == NULL)
                {
                    //Initialise the outbound struct
                    callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs = malloc(sizeof(callLogSearchOutboundStruct));
                    callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs->cleardownCause = NULL;
                    callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs->duration = 0;
                    callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs->target = NULL;
                    callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs->nextLeg = NULL;
                }
            outboundCallLegStartPtr = callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs;
            outboundCallLegStartPtr->nextLeg = NULL;
```

Below is the code that calls the function to insert the data into the linked list within the structure

```
insertOutboundLegToList(outboundCallLegStartPtr, targetBuffer, durationBuffer, atoi(rowReport[cleardownColIndex]), debugFile);
```

Below is the code for the actual insert function

```
void insertOutboundLegToList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundLeg, char * target, float duration, int cleardown, FILE * debugFile)
{
    //fprintf(debugFile, "INSIDE INSERT OUTBOUND LEG FUNCTION\n");
    if (outboundLeg->target == NULL)
    {
        outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
        outboundLeg->duration = duration;
        outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
        //fprintf(debugFile, "Outbound target is: %s\n", outboundLeg->target);
    }
    else
    {
        while (outboundLeg->nextLeg != NULL)
        {
            outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
        }
        outboundLeg->nextLeg = (callLogSearchOutboundStruct*)malloc(sizeof(callLogSearchOutboundStruct));
        outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
        outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
        outboundLeg->duration = duration;
        outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
        //fprintf(debugFile, "Outbound target is: %s\n", outboundLeg->target);
        outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
    }


}
```

Below is how I call the function to check if the structures need to be reallocated

```
if (reallocateStructures(&callLogSearch, &callLogSearchData, &switches, &timesStructHasBeenReallocated, currentStructIndexValue, dataRow) == 0)
                    {
                        //Structures have been reallocated so reset the index
                        currentStructIndexValue = -1;
                    }
```

And below is the actual function for the reallocation of the structures

```
int reallocateStructures(callLogSearchResultStruct **callLogSearch, callLogSearchDataStruct ** callLogSearchData, 
        switchIDStructure ** switches, int *timesStructHasBeenReallocated, int currentStructIndexValue,
        int dataRow)
{
    int INITIAL_CALL_STRUCT_SIZE = 100;
    int currentSize = 0;
    int newSize = 0;
    int initFromIndex = 0;
    callLogSearchResultStruct * callLogSearchTemp;
    callLogSearchDataStruct * callLogSearchDataTemp;
    switchIDStructure * switchesTemp;


    printf("Current Struct Index Value: %i\n", currentStructIndexValue);

    if (currentStructIndexValue >= INITIAL_CALL_STRUCT_SIZE) {
        printf("REALLOCATING STRUCTURES");
        currentSize = currentStructIndexValue * *timesStructHasBeenReallocated;

        newSize = currentSize + INITIAL_CALL_STRUCT_SIZE;
        *timesStructHasBeenReallocated = *timesStructHasBeenReallocated + 1;


        callLogSearchTemp = (callLogSearchResultStruct*)realloc(*callLogSearch, (newSize * sizeof(callLogSearchResultStruct)));
        callLogSearchDataTemp = (callLogSearchDataStruct*)realloc(*callLogSearchData, (newSize * sizeof(callLogSearchDataStruct)));
        switchesTemp = (switchIDStructure*)realloc(*switches, (newSize * sizeof(switchIDStructure)));


        /**callLogSearchData = realloc(*callLogSearchData, newSize * sizeof (callLogSearchDataStruct));
        *callLogSearch = realloc(*callLogSearch, newSize * sizeof (callLogSearchResultStruct));
        *switches = realloc(*switches, newSize * sizeof (switchIDStructure));
        */
        for (initFromIndex = currentSize; initFromIndex < newSize; initFromIndex++) {
            callLogSearchDataTemp[initFromIndex].aParty = NULL;
            callLogSearchDataTemp[initFromIndex].bParty = NULL;
            callLogSearchDataTemp[initFromIndex].cleardownCause = NULL;
            callLogSearchDataTemp[initFromIndex].date = NULL;
            callLogSearchDataTemp[initFromIndex].duration = 0;
            callLogSearchDataTemp[initFromIndex].outboundLegs = NULL;
            callLogSearchDataTemp[initFromIndex].time = NULL;

            callLogSearchTemp[initFromIndex].date = NULL;
            callLogSearchTemp[initFromIndex].dRowIndex = dataRow;

            switchesTemp[initFromIndex].switchID = NULL;
        }

        *callLogSearch = callLogSearchTemp;
        *callLogSearchData = callLogSearchDataTemp;
        *switches = switchesTemp;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I've tried running my program through Valgrind but I'm not entirely sure what all the messages mean and doing a Google, although I've found something, haven't help me to understand the problem.

The messages from Valgrind are

```
==9152== Invalid read of size 4
==9152==    at 0x80544EB: GenerateCallLog (performreport.c:3112)
==9152==    by 0x804AA49: ProcessReport (performreport.c:344)
==9152==    by 0x8056C7E: PerformReportCheck (reportcheck.c:72)
==9152==    by 0x80494D0: main (main.c:82)
==9152==  Address 0x47b22b0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==9152==
==9152== Invalid read of size 4
==9152==    at 0x80545CF: GenerateCallLog (performreport.c:3123)
==9152==    by 0x804AA49: ProcessReport (performreport.c:344)
==9152==    by 0x8056C7E: PerformReportCheck (reportcheck.c:72)
==9152==    by 0x80494D0: main (main.c:82)
==9152==  Address 0x47b22b0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==9152==
==9152== Invalid write of size 4
==9152==    at 0x80545DF: GenerateCallLog (performreport.c:3124)
==9152==    by 0x804AA49: ProcessReport (performreport.c:344)
==9152==    by 0x8056C7E: PerformReportCheck (reportcheck.c:72)
==9152==    by 0x80494D0: main (main.c:82)
==9152==  Address 0x35c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Line performreport.c:3112 is 
`if (dataRow > -1 && callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs == NULL)`

The line of performreport.c:3123 is 
`outboundCallLegStartPtr = callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs;`

The line of performreport.c:3124 is `outboundCallLegStartPtr->nextLeg = NULL;`, its this line that is also causing the core dump after the reallocations have occurred

The setCallResult function as requested is as follows:

```
char * setCallResult(int callResult)
{
    if (callResult == 1)
    {
        return "Answered";
    }
    else if (callResult != 3)
    {
        return "Unanswered";
    }
    else if (callResult == 3)
    {
        return "Engaged";
    }
    else
    {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

Sorry, for all of the code, but I don't know exactly where the problem might be. Looking in the core dump it looks as if something is trashing the memory as when I inspect some of the values within the structures its just garbled mess.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: It means you're reading an uninitialized variable at performreport.c:3480. If you're reading a pointer and then accessing data through that pointer, you lose. I can't tell where that line is, based on a snippet. Only you can tell us. But try to read valgrind's output, it's really not that hard.

Comment: Sorry, with all the changes I've made I took something out by mistake so it wasn't initialising it. The problem seems to be after the realloc is done on the structures, that when it does ``outboundCallLegStartPtr->nextLeg = NULL`` after it has been reallocated it crashes and if I try to print it it says its out of bounds, so something in realloc is screwing up the memory but I can't see what

Comment: Could you clearly mark line `performreport.c:3480` in the function `insertOutboundLegToList` please?

Comment: @us2012 that message has changed now due to previous comments. I have updated the question with the new message from Valgrind, however the same error occurrs

Comment: @Boardy I don't see any further obvious problems, but I feel that to solve the remaining problems, you need someone to go over the entirety of the code. For example, the invalid read in the `if` line is probably caused by something not shown in your question. I'd also suggest thoroughly studying a few `valgrind`/`gdb` tutorials, the time spent on this will pay off tenfold later if you continue working with C.

Comment: What is `setCallResult()` ?

Comment: @us2012 I thought that might be the case, I have read through quite a lot of tutorials regarding valgrind and gdb and they make sense just not when I try to match it up with my code thanks for your help though

Comment: @joop. I have added the setCallResult function to my question. All it does is return a string based on the integer value to determine if a call was answered or unanswered etc

Comment: Ok. `currentSize = currentStructIndexValue * *timesStructHasBeenReallocated;` : I'd put a few asserts in the function to prevent index <= 0 (since you appear to use -1 as a sentinel value). BTW: is timesStructHasBeenReallocated initialised correctly?

Comment: Yea that's probably good idea, to check its not below 0. The timesStructHasBeenReallocated variable is initialised correctly as the first time it does the realloc the current size is 100, then the newSize is 200, the new size is calculated from this variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one potential problem I can see:

In `insertOutboundLegToList`, you seem to take the first condition to mean "there is an allocated struct, but it's empty and yet to be filled". You then fill it, but you forget `NULL`ing `nextLeg`. So suppose that `nextLeg` is `0x75732d42` because that's the data still in there; next time the function is called, you trigger the `else` condition:

```
while (outboundLeg->nextLeg != NULL)
        {
            outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg;
        }
```

Now `nextLeg` isn't `NULL` even though it should be. After one iteration, `outboundLeg` points to `0x75732d42` even though there is no allocated struct there. On the next iteration, you crash because you try to read from an invalid memory address.

---

What I'm suggesting is this (in `insertOutboundLegToList`):

```
if (outboundLeg->target == NULL)
{
    outboundLeg->target = strdup(target);
    outboundLeg->duration = duration;
    outboundLeg->cleardownCause = strdup(setCallResult(cleardown));
    // HERE v HERE v HERE v HERE
    outboundLeg->nextLeg = NULL;
    ...
}
```

---

Also, this line in the realloc function

```
*callLogSearchData = callLogSearchData;
```

is probably missing a `Temp`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Where should I be ``NULL``ing outboundLeg->nextLeg

Comment: Ah yea that makes sense. I've done that still got the original problem though

Comment: @Boardy Still the same lines in `valgrind`/`gdb`? Please mark the lines given to you by the debug tool in your source code.

Comment: @Boardy Updated with another hint.

Comment: thanks, don't know how many times I've looked at that function and never noticed that. Valgrind has still got the original error but there is another error before it so I have updated my question. It doesn't seem to have affected though where it core dumps